# How to have excel display alert message pop up in the foreground of command prompt?

Tags: excel, powershell

So basically, whenever I run my PowerShell script the excel display alert shows up behind the command prompt and I want it to pop up in front of the command prompt having focus.I haven't had any luck finding a solution to it.

This is my code for the script

```bash
$file = 'path'
$excl = New-Object -ComObject 'Excel.Application'

if ($file.readonly) {
    Exit
}
try {
    $wrkb = $excl.Workbooks.Open($file)
}
Catch {
    Exit
}

$excl.DisplayAlerts = $TRUE

try {
    $wrkb.Save()
}
catch {
    Exit
}
```